# Is it possible to combine the result of a query with an edit?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Suppose I got this xml file:

```
<xml>
        <Attribute name="attribute1">
                <Value1>True</Value1>
                <Value2>True</Value2>
                <ID>1</ID>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="attribute2">
                <Value1>True</Value1>
                <Value2>True</Value2>
                <ID>2</ID>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="attribute3">
                <Value1>True</Value1>
                <Value2>True</Value2>
                <ID>3</ID>
        </Attribute>
</xml>
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Retrieve the value of the "name" attribute (I used `sel -t -m "xml" -m "Attribute" -v "@name"` for this)
2. Use the retrieved value and update the according ID element of the node so the result says e.g for attribute1 `<ID>attribute1</ID>`

Is this possible with XmlStarled?

Comment: I can't get closer without XSLT: `xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//xml/Attribute/ID' --expr '../@name' file.xml`

Comment: This is amazing, it's working, thank you very much!